# Not able to understand Angular's ControlValueAccessor working

Tags: angular

Can anyone tell me what does the below line means in terms of **ControlValueAccessor**'s method **registerOnChange()**:

> Registers a callback function that should be called when the control's value changes in the UI.

And it would be helpful if someone can explain what below code does:

```
registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
  this._onChange = fn;
}
```

I have read all the available link; but still i can not figure out how it works.

**Note**: I am not using this implementation for custom elements.